# why my django slug is not working properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to allow user to search in database for the topic. and show the topic name in url. 
I already created slug field in database but when i am trying to fetch the data from the database the url is not showing correctly.

url is showing:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/topic/<slug:topicname>/
```

what I want to show:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/topic/introduction-to-python/
```

My urls.py file

from django.urls import path
from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.apphome),
    path('topic/<slug:topicname>/', views.searchtopic, name = 'searchtopic'),

]
```

My model for the project

```
class blogposts(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 150, null=True, blank = True)
    post = models.TextField(max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic
```

This is my view

```
def searchtopic(request,topicname):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        topicname = request.POST.get('searchtopicname')

        mypost = mypostlist.objects.filter(slug = topicname)        
        context = {
            'mypost':mypost,
            }
        return render(request, 'blog/result.html',context)
```

My form for searching topic

```
<form action="topic/<slug:topicname>/" method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="search" placeholder="Search topics or keywords" name="searchtopicname">
       <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'GET' method insted of 'POST'
replace form with:

```
<form action="{%url 'searchtopic' %}" method="GET">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="search" placeholder="Search topics or keywords" name="searchtopicname">
   <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

replace urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.apphome),
path('topic/', views.searchtopic, name = 'searchtopic'),
]
```

replace views:

```
def searchtopic(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    topicname = request.GET['searchtopicname']

    mypost = mypostlist.objects.filter(slug = topicname)        
    context = {
        'mypost':mypost,
        }
    return render(request, 'blog/result.html',context)
```

Comment: showing NoReverseMatch - Reverse for 'searchtopic' with no arguments not found.

Comment: @Prakash Do you have to use 'POST' method?

Comment: @Prakash I changed the answer.

Comment: now showing - searchtopic() missing 1 required positional argument: 'topicname' i tried adding slug in url but its still not working

Comment: @Prakash excuse me, I updated answer. Please remove 'topicname' argument from 'searchtopic' method.